# Oracle Designer Editor 10.1.2.5 version control?

Tags: oracle, version-control, oracle10g, designer

I'm working in a company whose has installed an Oracle Designer Editor 10.1.2.5. We're using it for having the same copy of the database schema in dev/pre/prod enviroments.

The problem is that it does not have version control. So today, I accidentaly deleted a table and it was very awful to recover this. I spent all day.

I know this is a very old enviroment, but I would like to add version control to this. Do you know any way to do this? any plug-in maybe?

How can I add version control to Oracle Designer Editor 10.1.2.5?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Which version control system do you hope to use?

If you're using either Subversion or TFS, then we might have good news for you. [Red Gate Source Control for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/source-control-for-oracle/) could meet your needs. This lets you link a development database to a folder in your version control repository, allowing you to commit any changes for safekeeping. We'd welcome your feedback if you get a chance to try it.